# windows7 never loads updates

Tags: windows-7, updates

I have an clean install of windows7 on a gateway E-295c tablet laptop. It is the first time I have tried to update this PC, and it never completes the update process. The computer is still usable, I wouldn’t say it has hanged up.
The osculating blue bar just continues. I left it overnight and came back today, and its still going, so I think its not loading.

I know y’all probably want an error message, but it never terminates, and never returns any such error messages. Yes, I have tried rebooting, and shutting down.

I have it online, with an Ethernet patch cable. is there some sort of fix I should try? Should I try to get some individual packages to update first?
what should I do?

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: Looked for error messages in the system logs, and searched technet for solutions to similar issues. Also, I'm trying to get individual patches and hot fixes to see if any of them get me out of this. currently trying KB942871 patch, manual install

Comment: I assume you have tried rebooting. Sorry for the basic step, just thought I might see that in your response.

Answer (score 0):

I left it updating over the long weekend. (honestly, I forgot it was running.) when I returned from holiday, I noticed it was running still, same a s before. so i shut it down. During the shut down, it said Updating 53 of 201. so... I guess the problem is solved. (in that I might no longer have the issue. no idea what happened though.) maybe one of the manual updates worked some magic.